# Ubuntu freezes after upgrade

Tags: upgrade, 16.10, freeze, 17.04

I decided to move on from Ubuntu LTS 16.04 yesterday and started upgrading it, I upgrade to 16.10 and after installing all the updates I had one freeze that I didn't care about too much and just force restarted my computer (I never had a freeze in 16.04). Then I started the 17.04 upgrade, when it finished and restarted, random freezes kept happening, it can happen after hours or right after I restart my computer.

So I decided to reinstall the 17.04, downloaded it and made a boot-able USB and installed it, I have my /home directory on a separate partition so I don't loose any precious data, but even after re-installation I still have the random freezes.

I noticed it happened a lot when I am using Chrome, found some links talking about disabling hardware acceleration, but that didn't help too, so I just stopped using it. My computer worked fine again for hours but that didn't last... it has just froze again when I pasted some code onto PyCharm...

Any ideas on how to fix this? I am starting to think about reverting back to 16.04, but that's not a solution!

Edit: seems like it freezes while playing videos (in video player not browser) too

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your suffering from the same bug as me, #1674838

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1674838

The fix isn't out yet, the latest comment from Friday says "... the kernel which should be available in -proposed sometime
next week...".

So for now I've set my updates to get pre-release updates in anticipation of getting a stable system back again later this week.

If you do want to do more work tracking down the exact cause of your problem, it was setting up Netconsole that helped me identify my problem. See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Netconsole for instructions on that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will check this out asap! I hope this is the same thing and the fix gets released soon